# How does a shortcut work on a flash drive when the drive letter may change?

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive

If a flash drive contains a shortcut to another file on the drive - how does it still point to the same file if the drive letter changes? e.g. the path was **D**:/abc/def.txt and now it's **E**:/abc/def.txt.

I would think that the shortcut would be to a relative path but when viewing the shortcut's properties, the value given in "Target" is absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how does it still point to the same file if the drive letter changes?

It doesn't.  Which is really frustrating.

> the value given in "Target" is absolute

Sadly, this is the way it is. However, Windows *does* automatically fix broken shortcuts if it can, using some [fancy logic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776891(v=vs.85).aspx#Shellink_Link_Resolution). You will *probably* find that your shortcuts still work even after a drive letter change. The shortcuts will magically update themselves as you use them.

**My Advice**

If possible, give your USB keys the same letter on all your Windows PCs. Skip a few letters first though (so as to leave room for hard drives and new USB keys you may insert in the future, before you get a chance to change the drive letter).

I've assigned my first USB key the letter `J:` and the rest go from there. I've never had an issue with drives or USB keys changing letters since.

Comment: Before posting the question, I tested a link and it did still work. Perhaps because of the shell link resolution you linked to. But - How did you "assign" a letter to your flash drive? All I know is that it's done automatically by the OS.

Comment: @ispiro http://windows.microsoft.com/en-nz/windows/change-add-remove-drive-letter#1TC=windows-7